# Seleccionar un registro entre 2 registros con distintos valores en sus campos (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla de productos:

| MARCA | CATEGORIA | MODELO | CANTIDAD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SEGA | VIDEOJUEGOS | GENESIS | 2 |
| SEGA | VIDEOJUEGOS | SATURN | 1 |
| SEGA | VIDEOJUEGOS | GENESIS | 5 |

Lo que necesito es que después de realizar la consulta ya sea con Store procedure o Select me quede de la siguiente forma:

| MARCA | CATEGORIA | MODELO | CANTIDAD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SEGA | VIDEOJUEGOS | GENESIS | 7 |

Lo intente creando esta VIEW:

```
SELECT marca, categoria, modelo, SUM(cantidad) AS cantidad
FROM productos
WHERE (marca = 'sega') 
como v_suma
```

luego realice un:

```
SELECT DISTINCT marca, categoria, modelo MAX(cantidad) as Cantidad
FROM v_suma
```

Pero me da como resultado esto:

| MARCA | CATEGORIA | MODELO | CANTIDAD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SEGA | VIDEOJUEGOS | GENESIS | 7 |
| SEGA | VIDEOJUEGOS | SATURN | 1 |

La idea  es que después de haber sumado los que tenían el mismo modelo, me deje solo uno, independiente del modelo y que siempre sea el de mayor cantidad.

Favor su ayuda, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Jason podrias decir si las respuestas dadas te resultaron utiles, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes extraer el primer elemento utilizando Top.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEMP;
Create table #temp (Marca varchar(10), Categoria varchar(20), Modelo varchar(20), Cantidad int)
Insert into #temp (MARCA, Categoria, Modelo, Cantidad)
VALUES
('SEGA','VIDEOJUEGOS','GENESIS',2),
('SEGA','VIDEOJUEGOS','SATURN',1),
('SEGA','VIDEOJUEGOS','GENESIS',5);


With cte as (
SELECT Marca, Categoria, Modelo, SUM(CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD
    FROM #temp T
    WHERE T.Marca = 'SEGA'
    Group by Marca, Categoria, Modelo 
)
Select top(1) * 
    From cte 
ORDER BY CANTIDAD DESC 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEMP;
```

[image: Res1]

Pero eso solo te valdría para una Categoría.
Si tienes más de una, la manera más simple, es utilizar Row_Number, para numerar las filas. Particionando por marca y categoría. Escoges en la salida la fila 1.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEMP;
Create table #temp (Marca varchar(10), Categoria varchar(20), Modelo varchar(20), Cantidad int)
Insert into #temp (MARCA, Categoria, Modelo, Cantidad)
VALUES
('SEGA','VIDEOJUEGOS','GENESIS',2),
('SEGA','VIDEOJUEGOS','SATURN',1),
('SEGA','CONSOLAS','X',1),
('SEGA','VIDEOJUEGOS','GENESIS',5);


With cte as (
SELECT Marca, Categoria, Modelo, 
        SUM(CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD,
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by marca, categoria order by marca, categoria) as rn
    FROM #temp T
    WHERE T.Marca = 'SEGA'
    Group by Marca, Categoria, Modelo 
)
Select cte.Marca, cte.Modelo, cte.CANTIDAD
    From cte 
where rn= 1

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEMP;
```

[image: Res3]

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo justamente esto necesitaba realizar, Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener ese resultado debes utilizar la **cláusula group by**, la cual te permite agrupar registros por uno o varios campos:

```
SELECT 
 marca, 
 categoria, 
 modelo, 
 SUM(cantidad) AS cantidad 
FROM productos 
WHERE marca = 'sega'
Group by marca, categoria, modelo;
```

En este caso agrupas por **3** campos y aplicas la **función de agregación sum** obteniendo el total deseado.

Comment: La primera respuesta era la solución que buscaba, muchas gracias por responder, saludos.